# How to copy directory with rsync to remote USB pen drive correctly

Tags: rsync

How to copy dir-tree form Debian 11 to remote pen drive in a way, that I can restore this directory to the OS without any permission modifications?

A usb pen drive is mounted to `/home/<user>/mnt` at the `<host>` PC. Permission of this directory and format of the pen drive  is:

```
$ ls -la ./mnt
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 20:10 ..

$ sudo fdisk -l | grep sdb
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Disk /dev/sdb: 29,85 GiB, 32027705344 bytes, 62554112 sectors
/dev/sdb1        2048 62554111 62552064 29,8G 83 Linux
```

Then I mounted **remotely** the usb pen drive (`/home/<user>/mnt`) to `/mnt/remoteusb` via:

```
$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions <user>@<host>:/home/<user>/mnt /mnt/remoteusb

$ ls -la /mnt/remoteusb/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 20 22:52 ..
```

After this setup I tried to copying files via rsync, but still get following three categories of warnings (13, 95, 74), though I'm not modify permission or time stamps:

```
$ sudo rsync -aAXHv /var/lib /mnt/remoteusb --log-file=/home/user/rsynclog.log --no-perms --omit-dir-times | grep failed

rsync: [receiver] chown "/mnt/remoteusb/lib/gdm3/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.root.S3P7V1.j1LLd2" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: [receiver] rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr("/mnt/remoteusb/lib/systemd/.random-seed.oerYo2","user.random-seed-creditable") failed: Operation not supported (95)
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/mnt/remoteusb/lib/ucf/cache/.:etc:apt:apt.conf.d:50unattended-upgrades.ustIa1" failed: Bad message (74)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sshfs, the permissions are limited in accordance to the `<user>` you are using for making the connection. Actually, you do not need to use sshfs at all.

I recommend using rsync directly (under the hood, it uses ssh, too). You need to use the root user both locally and on the server-side like this:

```
sudo rsync -aAXHv /var/lib root@<host>:/root/mnt
```

Comment: I'd say this is 100% on point; but note that it's pretty common for file systems used on USB pen drives (FAT, NTFS) not to support extended attributes at all. In which case just putting an archive on that drive will work; the good ole `tar cf - /var/lib | zstd -5 ` piped through ssh to a file on the pen drive trick.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you mean since using FAT or NTFS target there is no difference to a standard archive?

Comment: @Hölderlin no, the opposite: NTFS and FAT *can't* hold the extended attributes which at least /mnt/remoteusb/lib/systemd/.random-seed.oerYo2 seems to carry. Putting things in an archive would enable you to keep them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, and to restore, I can just unpack the archive and override `/var/lib`?

Comment: yes, that'd work. Your whole sshfs setup is strange, however.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, I blatantly assumed a compatible filesystem like ext4 on the pen drive.

Comment: @Hermann fair enough, and it's strange that there's exactly a single failure to apply an xattr, but that's what I have to go on. Hölderlin, could you actually check what the file system on the pen drive is?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, for the format see my edits and if I would apply your suggestion using tar, I need `sshfs` because there is not enough space to create first the tar and then pipe it via `scp`.

Comment: @Hermann thx for the hint that rsync use `ssh` under the hood.

Comment: @Hölderlin I didn't say "pipe it via `scp`" (that makes no sense, by the way), I said "pipe it through ssh", avoiding *exactly* that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller if I got you, you mean `tar czf - /home/localuser/filefolder | ssh <user>@<host>:/home/remoteuser/` will not create the archive directly on the remote machine. Interesting point, till now I thought pipes like `program1 | program2` has to complete program1 at first before transfer the output to program2.

Comment: No, I don't mean that, because that's not how SSH works :) But I think you mean the right thing; I pipe things into a program (e.g., a shell) that writes them to disk, or directly "unpacks" the things as they come in.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you say "pipe it through ssh". For me ssh (SSH client) is a program for logging into- and executing commands on a remote machine. If executing `tar cz filesToArchive | ssh host "cat > /path/to/new.file"` I expected the tar command creates a archive on the local machine and then pass it to ssh. But as you mentioned, the data is not saved locally after being compressed by tar. Instead, it is passed through the ssh connection to the remote machine and saved there. And this was a new thing for me.